# Sci-fi short story: people can choose to be resurrected when they die, romantic tragedy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have been trying to find the title of a story that I read years ago and have hit a brick wall.

The basic premise is a future in which people can choose to be resurrected when they die. A married woman dies, I think unexpectedly, and has opted in to be resurrected.
She does not, however, have any attachment to her husband, who grieves for her. She hangs with other resurrected folk, who travel the globe. I seem to remember that the husband follows her, attempting to reunite and is rejected.
If memory serves, the husband dies, is resurrected, and learns that he no longer loves his wife.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Do you have a approximate publication date, any other information? You might also want to choose a more description question title.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that is ["Born with the Dead"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50858) by [Robert Silverberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Silverberg), which was also the (unaccepted) answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38474/looking-for-robert-silverberg-story-about-the-dead-being-returned-to-life). Here's the description from [The Quasi-Official Robert Silverberg Web Site](http://majipoor.com/work.php?id=112) (emphasis added):

> This story was written for a special Silverberg issue of *F&SF* and won the Nebula Award for best novella, 1975.
> **In the 1990s, doctors have discovered how to rekindle dead people, re-animating the bodies and minds.** But the deads are different, aloof, unconcerned with the matters of warms — those still alive — and mostly keep to the Cold Towns. **Jorge Klein finds that he cannot let go of his dead wife Sybille, and seeks her out obsessively, following her around the globe.** This is just not done, but Jorge can't stop himself.
> One interesting scene involves an African preserve set aside for vacationing deads, where they must leave the native animals alone and hunt instead genetically recreated extinct species — aurochs, ground sloth, quagga, passenger pigeon, dodo. Many aspects of the situation are explored, including the attitudes people of different cultures have towards death. Definitely one of the high points of Silverberg's career and the culmination of his intense and intimate writing of the 1970s.

Comment: @user14111 -- Many thanks; your addition is perfect.

Comment: That's it! A thousand thanks!!!

Comment: @D.Doe -- Glad to help; don't forget to accept it (the check box, under the voting arrows) if it's the correct answer.