# Looking for book in which people convert to another existence after physical death

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

From what I remember, the protagonist's wife dies, and gets "resurrected" into the dead community. He wants to contact her, she wants nothing to do with him. He pursues her, poses as a dead person to enter the dead colony etc. In the end, she arranges that he be killed so he stops pestering her.

Comment: Any other information you can remember, even if it seems trivial, would be good to add to your question. Consider taking a look at [this post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31051) for ideas on the kind of information that we find helpful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe this is ["Born with the Dead"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50858) by Robert Silverberg, described as follows [here](http://www.omphalosbookreviews.com/index.php/reviews/info/224):

> In Born with the Dead Jorge Klein has recently lost his wife, Sybille, but Sybille has undergone a procedure called "rekindling" where she was awakened after her natural death by a new medical procedure. After being rekindled she lived in a "Cold Town" with others of her kind, but in the years after the deads started to emerge slowly to the world of the "warms," where they travelled as tourists or continued on with their life's work. Sybille was doing post doc work on cultures in Zanzibar when she passed. She and a group of four other "deads" went on a world tour that ended in Zanzibar where Sybille intended to finish her research and publish. However Jorge was convinced that he was still in love with Sybille, and broke strong taboo by trying to reconnect with her after she was rekindled. Jorge's best friend, a Parsee named Jijibhoi was also a post doc anthropologist who spent his time trying to pierce the tight culture of the deads. Jijibhoi helped Jorge in his numerous efforts to get an audience with Sybille, even though he thought Jorge's compulsions were unhealthy and ill-conceived. Despite the other dead's attempts to block, Jorge did meet with Sybille a few times before he tracked her to Zanzibar, where the other deads grew tired of his complete misunderstanding of their culture and killed him, then sent him for his own rekindling.

It's also been a subject of previous questions here, a [couple](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/139783/65768) [times](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/38474/65768).

Comment: Yes, thank you, this is exactly it.